# xmldoc.selectNodes() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<resultset morerecords="0" paging-cookie="&lt;cookie page=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;activityid last=&quot;{2FCC78E0-EC60-E011-9854-000C291F081D}&quot; first=&quot;{2FCC78E0-EC60-E011-9854-000C291F081D}&quot; /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;">
    <result>
        <activityid>{2FCC78E0-EC60-E011-9854-000C291F081D}</activityid>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

And I am trying to get each activityid tag from the xml using `xmldoc.selectNodes("//activityid")` however, I am not getting the expected result.
The error I am getting is 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'.
My XPath is correct and also the javascript seems correct. What could be wrong?

EDIT:
Accessing it with the random access operator([]) works but for (... in ...) doesn't.
Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure you did not leave out any namespaces "for simplicity/brevity"? If you are not used to taking namespaces into account, it is quite easy to forget about them in xpath expressions…

Comment: @mousio: Nice try but no, I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [if '&' is present](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2906396/JAVASCRIPT-selectNodes-returns-0-if-XML-contains-c.aspx) then ['selectNodes' function does not select any row](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/511747-how-do-i-get-specific-node-xmldocument).

Comment: Luckily random access does work so I gave up for (... in ...)